# What does it mean to say the harmonic mean is a non-Lagrangian average?

Tags: mean, harmonic-mean

A [paper by Grabisch et al (2011)](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00539028/document) states that the arithmetic and geometric means are Lagrangian means whereas the harmonic mean is not Lagrangian.

What does this mean? What properties does a Lagrangian mean have and what properties do non-Lagrangian means have?

**References**

- Michel Grabisch, Jean-Luc Marichal, Radko Mesiar, Endre Pap. [Aggregation functions: Means.](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00539028/document) Information Sciences, Elsevier, 2011, 181 (1), pp.1-22. <10.1016/j.ins.2010.08.043>.

Comment: In its current edited form this is quite unclear. Some of the detail you deleted might be helpful for people to know just what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Skimming through the document, we see that Definition 27 defines the Lagrangian mean associated with a given continuous and strictly monotonic function $f$ on the unit interval.

At other places, the geometric and arithmetic mean are identified as Lagrangian. That is, there are functions $f_g$ and $f_a$ such that the geometric and arithmetic mean are exactly the Lagrangian means associated to $f_g$ and $f_a$ in the sense of Definition 27.

Conversely, it is claimed that the harmonic mean is not Lagrangian. This means that there is *no* such function $f_h$ such that the harmonic mean is the Lagrangian mean associated with $f_h$.

Now it would probably be a good exercise for you to carefully prove these three statements. Since they are not explicitly proven in the paper, I assume they are not very hard to show.